# Is there any way to insert a line and CSS knows how to put it at the end of the row in a grid system?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

**Edit 18-06-2020 - I found the answer [break to new row with flex box](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/)

I am making a calendar Component in ReactJS. When I click on any day button in the calendar, I would like to show a full width Component, right below the row of the button I clicked, where I can select an hour-interval for reservations.

I am attaching an image so I can explain better.

[image: The calendar view in grid system]

Let's say I insert a `<div>` between 3 and 4, the remaining table moves down by 300px, even if I didn't insert it at the end of the grid system. First row stays in place, the rest of the table should slide down by 300px. The same with the rest.

My html with the days buttons looks like this:

```html
<div class="days">
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">25</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">26</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">27</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">28</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">29</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">30</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button  ">1</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button  ">2</div>
...
<div role="button" class="day-button  ">30</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button  ">31</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">1</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">2</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">3</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">4</div>
<div role="button" class="day-button otherMonth ">5</div>
</div>
```

My grid style css

```css
grid-display{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    column-gap: 0px;
    row-gap: 1em;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

[JSBIN code](https://jsbin.com/gizipaf/edit?html,css,output)

Do I really need to make containers for each row of the table?

Is there any way that CSS knows how to insert an element at the end of the row?

Comment: Thank you Michael Benjamin for editing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [break to new row with flex box](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/)